how to open a textgrid with Praatio when xmin = xmax
I try to open a textgrid with praatio :
from praatio import textgrid
tg = textgrid.openTextgrid(myfile)
But in this textgrid, it happen sometimes that xmin = xmax :
"intervals [11]: xmin = 3.34, xmax = 3.34, text = "[,]" (extract of my textgrid file)
And it makes an error: TextgridStateError: The start time of an interval (2.63) cannot occur after its end time (2.63)
With this error, impossible to open the .TextGrid..
I don't know how to work around this error. I have hundreds of textgrids to open, and I can't manually fix them when they have this kind of error... Some ideas?? :)

The best approach is to directly modify the TextGrid by opening it as a text file and removing the intervals when xmin = xmax.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
